# windows 10 how to reduce outer margin in word documents

Tags: windows

How do I reduce the outer margin (word Document) on even pages only (left-hand pages) of my booklet so that when it appears in print the text is equally centred on the page?

Comment: What version of Microsoft Word are you using?

Comment: There is a similar question at [Microsoft's Answers forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/different-margins-for-odd-and-even-pages-but-not/7babd9ba-70b6-4f01-bb5e-f92f0707670e?auth=1) for Word 2007; this might give you some useful pointers.

Comment: Why do you need to shift just the left pages?

Answer (score 0):

Use Page Layout dialog and setup Gutter and Gutter Position.

Comment: LOL - perhaps I am not the one that needs to read that.